# model compare by anova test

Tags: r, anova

I did model test of in anova. once mod1 vs mod2 , other mod2 vs mod1. Does it matter? Can I compare two models of different df and different parameters?

```
anova(reg5,reg4, test="Chisq")

Analysis of Variance Table
Model 1: Gas ~ CODload
Model 2: Gas ~ Flow * CODin
  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq  Pr(>Chi)    
1     65 27786                           
2     63 12835  2     14952 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> anova(reg4,reg5, test="Chisq")

Analysis of Variance Table
Model 1: Gas ~ Flow * CODin
Model 2: Gas ~ CODload

  Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq  Pr(>Chi)    
1     63 12835                           
2     65 27786 -2    -14952 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 2):

1) These tests are for comparing *nested* models (that is, where the smaller model could be obtained from the more general model if some of the parameters take specified values). Your models don't appear to be nested.

2) When you call `anova`, put the more general model (larger model d.f. & smaller residual d.f.) second. It feels backward to me but that appears to be how it works; see `?anova.lm`.

Comment: Even if the two models are not nested, it is still possible to apply `anova`. But in this case, the test statistic would be approximately Chi-square distributed.

Comment: @Stat Possibly. Under which conditions will that be the case?

Comment: I read it in the paper but I cannot recall the title! I am almost sure about it ... have no idea about the conditions.

Comment: @Stat if you see it again, I'd really love to read the details. It seems like there'd be problems with this (such as the smaller model sometimes having larger model sum of squares and sometimes smaller), so I assume there's some conditions required, but I can't see what they'd be.