# anova() for model comparision _ Regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, anova, multiple-regression, interpretation

let's suppose; I am fitting some models to a data set:

```
m1=lm(y~x1,data=data); m2=lm(y~x1+x2,data=data)
m3=lm(y~x1+x3, data=data); m4=lm(y~x2+x3, data=data)
m5=lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=data)
```

I want to understand the **use of anova() to compare different models**.

My questions are:

1. As discussed [model compare by anova test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93238/model-compare-by-anova-test?rq=1), I need to put more general model later. **So is anova(m2, m1) a wrong way of doing comparision?**
2. anova() can be used for nested models (models have a shared set of predictor variables and the same outcome variable, but one model has one or more additional predictor variables), **can we use anova(m2, m3) or anova(m1, m4)?**
3. How to interpret **output of anova() using three or more models**? For example; anova(m1, m2, m3) or anova(m1, m2, m3, m4).

-

Comment: Update: in 2019, a  new package 'performance' is released and as on date, we have version 0.7.2.
This package have cool functions not only to compare performance of various models but also for checking heteroskedasticity, normality of residual, autocorrelation, colinearity, outliers, model specification etc.
This model also provides other performance metrics like  r-squared, AIC, BIC, RMSE, ICC or LOOIC. Basically, no need to use separate package for these. 
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/performance/versions/0.7.2

Comment: Using performance package for model comparisons: https://github.com/arora123/R-for-Data-Science/blob/master/Comparing%20performance%20of%20linear%20models.r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you do `anova(m2, m1)` it computes the same p-value as `anova(m1, m2)` so the order is not crucial. However, in the former case the change in degrees of freedom becomes negative which might look confusing in the output. (As pointed out in the other Q/A you referred to.)
2. No. It is technically possible to enter `anova(m2, m3)` but the result is not a valid ANOVA. If you want to compare these models, you can either resort to information criteria (AIC, BIC, ...) or use dedicated tests for non-nested hypotheses (e.g., encompassing test, Vuong test, Cox test, J test, etc.).
3. If you carry out `anova(m1, m2, m5)` this reports two tests which essentially correspond to `anova(m1, m2)` and `anova(m2, m5)`. However, the error sum of squares is taken from `m5` in both of these comparisons which might lead to small differences. Due to 2. the sequence of models must be nested in each step to return valid ANOVAs. But you can do an encompassing test between `m2` and `m3` by going through `m5`, i.e., `anova(m2, m5, m3)`.

Comment: Thanks Achim. So, for anova(m1, m2, m5), we can infer that one of the models in increasing/decreasing order of RSS. E.g., The anova output on http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-anova-tables/ can be interpreted as: **Model 2 has lower RSS than Model 1 and Model 5 has Lowest RSS among the three models.** Please correct, if I'm wrong.

Comment: Please also share some resource for learning **non-nested hypotheses** (e.g., encompassing test, Vuong test, Cox test, J test, etc.). Thanks again

Comment: Interpretation of ANOVA: For concluding that the _RSS decreases_ you do not need a significance test. The point is whether it decreases significantly or not. In the blog post you link adding `HGRAD` in addition to `UNEM` improves the model significantly. And adding `INC` to the other two variables improves the model significantly again. As for non-nested hypotheses: This is covered, for example, in _Econometric Analysis_ by Greene.

Comment: And since @learner apparently uses R s/he might consider looking at the lmtest package and its documentation.

Comment: Thanks.Yeah, I meant statistically significant decrease in RSS